# Installing JavaBridge on Windows 8 for connecting BIRT with PHP web application

Tags: java, php, birt, php-java-bridge

i know that javabridge.war and birt.war needed for connecting java with php. but, there is a problem with my javabridge installation. can somebody help me how to install javabridge on windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to windows, but you can see the http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/install_server/ for how to build the war, then install Tomcat and deploy.